# Variável JavaScript undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou tentando passar um valor, através de um `input type hidden` do HTML gerado no PHP para o JavaScript, porém essa variável no JavaScript está como Undefined. O que pode ser?

PHP

```
<form name='form5' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='id-playlist' value='$consulta[id_playlist]'>
<input type='image' id='carregar-playlist' src='images/play-circle-24.png' alt='Botao'>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#carregar-playlist', function () {
    id_playlist=$("#id-playlist").val();
    alert(id_playlist);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para pegar o valor `$("#id-playlist")`, é necessario que no HTML esteja como:

```
<input type='hidden' id="id-playlist" name='id-playlist' value='$consulta[id_playlist]'>
```

Faltou o atributo `id = id-playlist` no HTML.

Comment: Na mosca! Valeu!